# Pre-initialize $mdDialog in Angular Material?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

The first time I call $mdDialog as below there is a short delay as it initialize. After that the animation is smooth.

Is there a way to preinitialize it so it is always smooth to the user?

```
    $mdDialog.show({
            //controller: optionsCtrl,
            templateUrl: 'partials/optionsDlg.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            openFrom: '#settingsButton',
            closeTo:'#settingsButton'
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using a pre-rendered dialog as seen [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#pre-rendered-dialogs). You must be on at least angular material 1.1.0-RC5. Use the option contentElement. You can pass in a selector string or a DOM element.

```
contentElement: '#myStaticDialog';
contentElement: document.querySelector('#myStaticDialog');
contentElement: angular.element(TEMPLATE);
```

> When using a template as content element, it will be not compiled upon
>   open. This allows you to compile the element yourself and use it each
>   time the dialog opens.